# Делаю чат. Проблема в том, что он работает только на одном компьютере

Tags: java, udp, чат

Делаю чат на `DatagramSocket`. Создаю для сервера сокет на нужном порте, который перед этим ввожу. При запуске программы вызываю функции:

`InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()`, что-бы знать к какому IP подключаться с клиентского приложения.

`DatagramSocket toReceive = new DatagramSocket(port);`, соответственно для создания сокета на нужном порте.

Потом запускаю клиентское приложение, создаю такой же сокет, но уже без указания порта. В `DatagramPacket`-ах указываю нужный IP, порт, все сообщения доходят и сервер их без проблем выводит на экран.

Но стоит мне только запустить клиентское приложение на другом компьютере, мои пакеты уже просто не доходят до сервера, хоть компьютеры и подключены к одной локальной сети.